create a minimal XZ-backdoor
I'd like to see a minimal example of the XZ backdoor.
As I understand it:

sshd code is not touched
using https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GNU_IFUNC a critical function is replaced

So sth like this (does not work yet!)
main.c (acting as sshd)
#include <stdio.h>

void critical_function() {
    printf("critical_function uncompromised.\n");
}

int main() {
    critical_function();
    return 0;
}

backdoor.c
#include <stdio.h>

void compromised_critical_function() {
    printf("critical_function COMPROMISED.\n");
}

void *resolve_critical_function() {
    return compromised_critical_function;
}

__attribute__((visibility("default")))
void critical_function() __attribute__((ifunc("resolve_critical_function")));

gcc-13 -o prog main.c
gcc-13 -shared -fPIC -o libbackdoor.so backdoor.c
LD_PRELOAD=./libbackdoor.so ./prog

this prints critical_function uncompromised. but I'd like it to print critical_function COMPROMISED.

How is this related to xz and backdoor and sshd?

@KamilCuk https://research.swtch.com/xz-script — Enjoy the read, it’s a super interesting hack. And it almost screwed us all over big time.

Except there never was any "attacker". Changes were made by a developer with full access to anything. The open source format was the true culprit. "Random unknown Internet people making me free software only have my best interests in mind" is beyond naive.

@Lundin Of course there was an attacker. And these things can happen (and have happened!) to closed-source projects as well.

@KonradRudolph The point is that in an open source project, nobody necessarily got a clue of who the other contributors are. If some random stranger shows up at my job, works for free and starts to commit code into the internal repo, I'm going to get a tad bit suspicious.

@Lundin There was a good amount of social engineering involved with this.  The contributor in question was part of the project for over two years making valid contributions and earning privileges in the project before the components that were part of the backdoor were added.

@dbush Still, I fail to see how this could have happened to a commercial product.

@Lundin Given that this has repeatedly happened in commercial products via infiltration of software and hardware companies, I am confused by your scepticism. As for “how”: usually by infiltrating the hiring process of a company.

@KonradRudolph But that would be way harder since you need a live person to show up in the flesh and take the risk working as the mole. And also make it seem that they are doing the same work as a whole team programmers. There aren't many James Bond types who have the social skills to pull that off while at the same time being proficient enough in niche technologies not to raise suspicion.

With an open source project you can have one person handling all the interactions without having a clue about technology, while at the same time having a whole team of asocial programmer nerds who perhaps don't even speak English in the background, doing the actual work.

@Lundin First off, remote work is a thing; “fake” employees are a fairly widespread problem. And even on-site workers can in practice offload a lot of the work to a background team. This actively happens (though mostly for the purpose of industrial espionage). It’s probably harder to pull off than on OSS projects but it’s far from impossible, and in practice as far as I’m aware there’s no evidence that OSS is more vulnerable to exploits than closed source software and/or commercial software.

@KonradRudolph Similarly, there is no evidence that "this has repeatedly happened in commercial products" either, you are making a whole lot of statements with no sources or references cases to back them. As for remote work, it is a relatively new phenomenon and wasn't nearly as common before Covid 19 as it is now.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don’t think this works with symbols that are statically combined into the binary. Those symbols are defined in the binary’s text section and are resolved statically:
nm prog | grep critical_function

                 T critical_function

To make the symbol lookup happen at runtime by the dynamic link editor (ld.so), you need to leave the symbol undefined (U in the nm nomenclature). You can do this by extracting critical_function into its own translation unit and compile it as a shared library that is linked to your binary:
main.c:
void critical_function(void);

int main(void) {
    critical_function();
}

func.c:
#include <stdio.h>

void critical_function(void) {
    printf("critical_function uncompromised.\n");
}

backdoor.c:
#include <stdio.h>

void compromised_critical_function(void) {
    printf("critical_function COMPROMISED.\n");
}

void *resolve_critical_function(void) {
    return compromised_critical_function;
}

__attribute__((visibility("default")))
void critical_function(void) __attribute__((ifunc("resolve_critical_function")));

Compiled via (Makefile):
CFLAGS += -fPIC

all: prog libbackdoor.so

prog: main.o libfunc.so
    $(CC) -o $@ $+

lib%.so: %.o
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $+

And execute via:
LD_PRELOAD=./libbackdoor.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD ./prog

critical_function COMPROMISED.


For completeness, you don’t need to use the IFUNC mechanism here to achieve this; IFUNC is useful to compute the function address dynamically at runtime, but we could just override it unconditionally:
backdoor.c (alternative)
#include <stdio.h>

void critical_function(void) {
    printf("critical_function COMPROMISED.\n");
}


Presumably, the xz library isn't loaded by sshd with LD_PRELOAD, so how would this work without doing that?

@dbush LD_PRELOAD is absolute not necessary: any dynamic loading of the library would cause this. So if the binary were linked to libbackdoor.so via the regular table entry at link time, the same would happen. — In reality, sshd doesn’t link to xz at all. But systemd used to (until a month or so ago!) side-load a bunch of libraries into the executables it launched (which includes sshd), and one of those libraries is xz, at least on some systems (that’s as far as my knowledge of the backdoor goes, I’m afraid).
